# Join using $expand in OData

Tags: join, odata, left-join, right-join

Is there a concept of Left Join and Right Join in OData.
Using $expand system query the result is inner join or left join.Please throw some light on this concept.

Answer (score 1):

There is a $crossjoin in ODL v4, but it is not implemented now. Fortunately, you can do the join inside an action in a controller that processes an OData Function requests. Please follow this sample:https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/.

Comment: Can you please tell if we want inner Join against a service that is using OData v2 .What URL to query ?

Answer (score 1):

$expand is similar to Left join. For example, Customers?$expand=Orders, it will return all Customers. If there is any order associated with a customer, it will also return the orders as a property of the Customer. You can check the online service http://odatae2etest.azurewebsites.net/demo/DefaultService/Customers?$expand=Orders with the $expand functionality.

Comment: What about inner join ? what will be the URL if we want inner Join? Talking from the client perspective